# prize distribution on the basis of rank using mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables one is prize table and one is result table

PRIZE TABLE

```
pm_id pm_fromrank pm_torank pm_prize  pool_id
1     1           1         1000       72
2     2           5         500        72
3     6           10        270        72
```

RESULT TABLE have 3 type of ranks case
1st CASE

```
  rs_id       rs_userid         rs_rank    rs_poolid
   1             131              1             72
   2             132              1             72
   3             133              2             72
   4             134              3             72
   5             135              4             72
   6             136              5             72
   7             137              6             72
   8             138              6             72
   9             139              7             72
   10            140              8             72
   11            141              9             72
   12            142              10            72
```

2ND CASE

```
 rs_id        rs_userid         rs_rank    rs_poolid
   1             131              1             72
   2             132              2             72
   3             133              3             72
   4             134              4             72
   5             135              5             72
   6             136              6             72
   7             137              7             72
   8             138              8             72
   9             139              9             72
   10            140              10            72
   11            141              11            72
   12            142              12            72
```

**3RD CASE**

```
rs_id        rs_userid        rs_rank     rs_poolid
   1             131              1             72
   2             132              2             72
   3             133              3             72
   4             134              4             72
   5             135              5             72
   6             136              6             72
   7             137              7             72
   8             138              8             72
   9             139              9             72
   10            140              10            72
   11            141              10            72
   12            142              10            72




now i have to distribute price only first 10 user in ascending order in following ways
1ST CASE PRIZE DISTRIBUTION
rs_id       rs_userid          rs_rank        rs_poolid      pricemoney
   1             131              1             72                750
   2             132              1             72                750
   3             133              2             72                500
   4             134              3             72                500
   5             135              4             72                500
   6             136              5             72                270
   7             137              6             72                270             
   8             138              6             72                270
   9             139              7             72                270
   10            140              8             72                270
   11            141              9             72                 0
   12            142              10            72                 0
```

2ND CASE PRIZE DISTRIBUTION

```
rs_id      rs_userid          rs_rank        rs_poolid        pricemoney
   1             131              1             72                1000
   2             132              2             72                500
   3             133              3             72                500
   4             134              4             72                500
   5             135              5             72                500
   6             136              6             72                270
   7             137              7             72                270             
   8             138              8             72                270
   9             139              9             72                270
   10            140              10            72                270
   11            141              11            72                 0
   12            142              12            72                 0
```

3RD CASE PRIZE DISTRIBUTION

```
rs_id        rs_userid          rs_rank      rs_poolid        pricemoney
   1             131              1             72                1000
   2             132              2             72                500
   3             133              3             72                500
   4             134              4             72                500
   5             135              5             72                500
   6             136              6             72                270
   7             137              7             72                270             
   8             138              8             72                270
   9             139              9             72                270
   10            140              10            72                 90
   11            141              10            72                 90
   12            142              10            72                 90
```

NOTE:- THE PRIZE TABLE AND RESULT TABLE HAVE RELATIONSHIP WITH POOL_ID
I have to find the prize distribution on the basis of rank using mysql and codeignitor

Comment: The algorithm of the prize distribution is absolutely unclear except the facts that the users with the same rank group (1st with ties, first 5 with ties, first 10) must receive equal money amount. Please formulate this algo explicitly and completely. Take into account the situation when 10th and 11th users have the same rank.

Comment: yes if first position have 10 ties then all prize money will get sum and divide by 10users on first rank but after 10 person no prize will distribute

Comment: Do not comment my guess. Edit the question and add **complete** algorithm description. *after 10 person no prize will distribute* Assume that 11 users have the same rank which is the highest. What user of these 11 ones will be deprived of the prize and why?

Comment: i think you are not able to understand by question i  already mention in question that only first 10 users will get prize if 11th user have same rank still prize will distribute to only first 10 person from top but the sum of prize now will divide by 10 person

Comment: In above question we need to consider two things first user with same rank and primary key so that we distribute prize only first 10 person

Comment: This is you who cannot understand. *if 11th user have same rank still prize will distribute to only first 10 person* - how to define who is this 11th from all these 11 users who will be deprived of the prize? why he and not somebody another? 'randomly' is not an answer... And I don't see the algorithm in your question still.

Comment: i mentioned that first  10 users will get prize and first 10 user will decide on the basis of table primary key how many time need to mention me same thing if you have not able to understand this question please leave it

Comment: The term "first" not exists until the ORDER BY expression which provides each row uniqueness is defined. What is this expression in your case? `ORDER BY rs_rank` does not match the uniqueness requirement on your data.

Comment: uniquesness will defined on rs_id so that we can take only first 10 users

Comment: I.e. `ORDER BY rs_rank DESC, rs_id`? well, this matches. Now please define precise algorithm which allows to calculate the amount of money for a user when the ranges are crossed. Why `pricemoney` in 1st example is 750? 1000 for 1st rank and 500 for 2nd rank are divided equally?

Comment: Now please provide **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: in 1st example 1000 prize money for  user on 1st rank but we have two user on 1st rank so we add 1000+500 and divide with 2 so that both user on 1st rank get 750 amount and since we have to give 500 for users on 2nd rank to 5th rank but we have 2 users on 1st rank now by primary key "rs_id" we give 500 to users  upto 5th rs_id and according to rank it is 4th rank

Comment: i am using heidisql 11.3 to manage mysql

Comment: heidisql is a client whereas you must provide the server version. Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for MySQL version 8+:

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rs_rank, rs_id) rn,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rs_rank) drnk
         FROM result
         ORDER BY rs_rank, rs_id LIMIT 10),
cte2 AS (SELECT cte1.drnk, SUM(prize.pm_prize) totalmoney
         FROM cte1 
         JOIN prize ON cte1.rn BETWEEN prize.pm_fromrank AND pm_torank
         GROUP BY cte1.drnk),
cte3 AS (SELECT *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rs_rank) drnk
         FROM result
         ORDER BY rs_rank, rs_id),
cte4 AS (SELECT MAX(drnk) max_drnk
         FROM cte1),
cte5 AS (SELECT rs_id, rs_rank, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rs_rank) rank_count
         FROM cte3
         JOIN cte4 ON cte3.drnk <= cte4.max_drnk)
SELECT result.*, cte2.totalmoney / cte5.rank_count pricemoney
FROM cte5
JOIN result USING (rs_id)
JOIN cte2 ON result.rs_rank = cte2.drnk
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e44b3d816f9890ca3da5674c2837a97e) with explanations.